# C++ Integral Approximation- For Loop function Addition

Tags: c++

Please bear with me as I am new to coding. I am trying to approximate the integral 4 / (1+x^2) from 0 to 1 using C++. I am required to use the formula:
P = 1/n [sum from i to n-1: f(x)] with x = (i+0.5)/n and i equal to 0, 1, 2, 3.... n-1.
Specifically I am struggling with writing the portion of the code to add f(x) for each value of x and i. This can be seen in the for loop towards the bottom of the code. I keep computing a value of 0, but this integral should be making an approximation of pi. Thank you in advance. Below is my code.

```
// Definite Integral using Quadrature Method
// As N increases, P approaches pi.
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;
double func(double x)        
{
double func = 4 /(1+x*x); // define function func = 4 / (1 +x^2) to be integrated
return func;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
if (argc < 2) {
std::cout << argv[0] << "n";
return 0;
}

int n = std::atoi(argv[1]);  // n is number of subintervals
std::cout << "n=" << n << std::endl;
std::cout << std::setprecision(16);


// P = (1/n)*[sum func((i+0.5)/n] with i = 0,1,2,3,... N-1 
int i;
double s, x;
for ( i=0; i<=(n-1); i++)          
{                
  x = (i + 0.5) / n;
  s = func(x);
  x += x;
  s += s;
     
 }


 double P = (1/n)*s;
  cout<< P;
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `1/n` : integer division, equal to 0. Moreover, the sum is not initialised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code. In your loop that calculates the sum, you are not initializing `s`. Also, you are resetting `s` to a different value every time you iterate, so the sum is not added correctly.

You can write the loop like this:

```
double s = 0;
for ( i=0; i<=(n-1); i++)          
{             
  double x = (i + 0.5) / n;
  s += func(x);     
}
```

Secondly, this computation `1/n` when you are computing `P` is incorrect. This will do integer division, and you will get `0` whenever `n` is greater than `1`. You need to do `1./n` instead. You could also simply do:

```
double P = s/n;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sTG6W8).